# How do I create CSS styled text "labels" (not html label tags)?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create some CSS text "labels" that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaTTp.jpg

I have adopted some code I found online and started to build it as a `<ul>` list, but it's not displaying correctly. Everything is stacked in the wrong order.

Maybe my list approach is entirely wrong.

Do you know what code I should be using to achieve the same look as in my example picture?

```css
 .list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
    
.list li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: #eee;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    margin-right: 10px;
}      

.triangle, .triangle2 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -10px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}  
      
.triangle2 {
    border-left-color: white;
    left: 0;
}
      
a {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 30px;  
    color: #111111;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <span class="triangle2"></span>
    <a href="#">Some text</a>
    <span class="triangle after"></span>
  </li>Some other text
  <li>
    <span class="triangle2"></span>
    <a href="#">Some text</a>
    <span class="triangle after"></span>
  </li>Some other text
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have not bind complete text within the `li`. Each `li` should have complete data within it to follow the standards of coding.

I have modified the `li` wrapped all text in the `li` and made changes in css

I'm using `display: inlnie-block`

Here is the [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/23533mh7/)

-Help :)

Comment: One small thing. I was hoping to switch between background colors within the list by applying a different class to each one. But since all the label colors are tied to '.list li > div:first-child' I can only change the entire list - not each label independently. Do you know how I can do that? Sorry I should have clarified that in original post.

Comment: Looks good, but now the left hand side white triangle is missing. Only the right hand side white triangle is working.